# How to load models with possibility to change textures in Three.js

Tags: models, blender, three.js, model-loader

I'm working on a game in Three.js where I have a few variations of the same model in blender.

What I want to achieve is that I'll load the model once with all the material settings, but then I'll just change the texture dynamically. Is there a way to do that? and in what format should I export it from blender in order to do this effeciently (json, obj)?

Thank you so much in advance.